# How do I test a Hive UDF for correct input?

Tags: unit-testing, hive

How can I verify that my RegEx going into a Hive UDF will work properly without running a bunch of Hive queries?

Such as

```
Select * from myTable Where regexp_extract(col, "([0-9]{4})");
```

How do I know that the RegEx "([0-9]{4})" will return the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

In Java the builtin UDFs are available to call directly.

```
public void testHiveUDF() {
    String patternStr = "([0-9]{4})";
    System.out.println((new UDFRegExpExtract()).evaluate("stuff1234", patternStr));
}
```

Thus a series of RegEx patterns could be tested rapidly with confidence that they will work in Hive as expected.

This testing can be expanded to other built in Hive UDFs.  Pick your favorite from [this list](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/UDF.html) to test the inputs.